# How can I have this $\LaTeX$ expression in my Mathematica code?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to make [this](https://www.overleaf.com/2727598tzjnzn#/7263958/) happen in Mathematica:

`$\mathscr{G}_{\text{\textbullet}}$`

$\mathscr{G}_{\text{\textbullet}}$

I tried

`ToExpression["\\mathscr{G}_{\\text{\\textbullet}}", TeXForm, HoldForm]`,

but I had to abort.

---

It might be worth mentioning that I had this inside a `Style`d `Text` graphic like this: `Style[Text[ToExpression["\\mathscr...` I'm pretty sure that's an important thing as to why this isn't working, but I'm not sure what to do to get the desired result. I need it to have a position, and the position is dynamically changing based on user input.

Comment: Why did you have to abort that evaluation? It quickly evaluates to G for me. However, I suspect that is not what you want. What would you like as the output?

Comment: Also, you can edit your own questions as many times as you'd like. Please put all information in the question, rather than in a stream of comments. Under the question, there is an "edit" link.

Comment: `\[ScriptCapitalG]` might be better option here...

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SpecialCharacters.html is really helpful.

Comment: Try `Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalG], \[FilledSmallCircle]]`, which you can enter as `esc` scG `esc` `ctrl` + `_` `esc` fsci `esc`.  For the empty circle, you can use  esci instead of fsci.